# How to reverse the string 'ab,cd,ef' to 'ef->cd->ab'

Tags: sql, string, oracle, reverse

when I select the table from Oracle, I want to handle one col'val :
eg:

```
'ab,cd,ef' to 'ef->cd->ab';
'AB,BC' to 'BC->AB';
'ACNN,BBCCAC' to 'BBCCAC->ACNN';
'BBBDC，DCCX，FFF' to 'FFF->DCCX->BBBDC'
```

Comment: http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/reverse-the-order-of-comma-separated-string-using-oracle-sql/

Answer (score 3):

We have two tasks.  The first is to tokenize the original strings.  This is quite easy with regular expressions (although [there are more performant approaches if you are dealing with large volumes](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2007/11/interval-based-row-generation.html)).  The second task is to re-assemble the tokens in reverse order;  we can use the 11gR2 [LISTAGG()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions100.htm#SQLRF30030) function for this:

```
with tokens as (
    select distinct col1, regexp_substr(col1, '[^,]+', 1, level) as tkn, level as rn
    from t23
    connect by level <= regexp_count (col1, '[,]')  +1
   )
select col1
       , listagg(tkn, '->') 
            within group (order by rn desc) as rev_col1
from tokens
group by col1
/
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4bc2/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a mix of **string split** and **string aggregation**.

Using:

- **REGEXP_SUBSTR** : To split the comma delimited string into rows
- **LISTAGG**       : To aggregate the values

You can have a look at this article to understand how string split works http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 ID, 'ab,cd,ef' text FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2 ID, 'AB,BC' text FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3 ID, 'ACNN,BBCCAC' text FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT ID,
  7    listagg(text, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  8  ORDER BY rn DESC) reversed_indices
  9  FROM
 10    (SELECT t.id,
 11      rownum rn,
 12      trim(regexp_substr(t.text, '[^,]+', 1, lines.COLUMN_VALUE)) text
 13    FROM data t,
 14      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
 15      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.text, ',')+1
 16      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
 17    ORDER BY ID
 18    )
 19  GROUP BY ID
 20  /

        ID REVERSED_INDICES
---------- ------------------------------
         1 ef,cd,ab
         2 BC,AB
         3 BBCCAC,ACNN

SQL>
```

Let's say your table looks like:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

        ID TEXT
---------- ------------------------------
         1 ab,cd,ef
         2 AB,BC
         3 ACNN,BBCCAC
         4 word1,word2,word3
         5 1,2,3

SQL>
```

Using the above query:

```
SQL> SELECT ID,
  2    listagg(text, '-->') WITHIN GROUP (
  3  ORDER BY rn DESC) reversed_indices
  4  FROM
  5    (SELECT t.id,
  6      rownum rn,
  7      trim(regexp_substr(t.text, '[^,]+', 1, lines.COLUMN_VALUE)) text
  8    FROM t,
  9      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
 10      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.text, ',')+1
 11      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
 12    ORDER BY ID
 13    )
 14  GROUP BY ID
 15  /

        ID REVERSED_INDICES
---------- ------------------------------
         1 ef-->cd-->ab
         2 BC-->AB
         3 BBCCAC-->ACNN
         4 word3-->word2-->word1
         5 3-->2-->1

SQL>
```